# I want to run wp_query on a separate php file for an ajax call

Tags: php, wordpress

For example:

```
<?php $numposts = $_POST['showposts']; ?>


<?php $home_query_bottom = new WP_Query("cat=&showposts=$num_posts&offset=5"); $b = 0; ?>
<ul class="thumbs">
    <?php while ($home_query_bottom->have_posts()) : $home_query_bottom->the_post();
        $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; $b++; ?>

        <li class="post-<?php the_ID(); ?> thumb"><?php get_the_image( array( 'custom_key' => array( 'thumbnail' ), 'default_size' => 'thumbnail', 'width' => '160', 'height' => '160' ) ); ?></li>
    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); $b = 0; ?>
</ul>
```

The code above is on its own php file ready to be called by the main wordpress page, however I get an error saying wp_query class not found. I'm assuming it's because I am not using the header.html which probably has a bunch of includes. What do I need for that page to utilize the wp_query class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make the page that ajax calls a template page.
Make a new page in your blog and assign the template.
no headers no includes.

Answer (score 7):

You can turn the template engine off and then include the header.
   `// Include WordPress

  define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);

  require_once('PATHHERE/wp-blog-header.php');`

Comment: include my header? But it's a ajax call that I want to load into my homepage

Comment: Thats why you turn off themes. header will load all the functions you need, but since themes are turned off it wont actually output the header content.

Comment: ah ok. Well i think my host disabled require_once and includes because I get URL file-access is disabled errors. Which makes me wonder how is wordpress including their essential classes etc...

Comment: I don't think wordpress would be able to run at all if requireonce/include were somehow disabled. Perhaps you are pointing it to a directory you don't have access to?

Comment: ok yes it doesn't like the absolute url paths include('mydoamin.com/wp-content/themes/fullscreen/header.php');

Comment: sorry it's just header.php because it was in the saem directory. Now im getting a call to an undefined function in my header.php which is language_attributes();

Comment: @MrGlass That surely removed the error for me, but I'm not getting any output. it gives a blank page. Oh, yeah what I'm trying to do is access my custom post types. Any idea? http://pastebin.com/cpBu7f54 this is the code.

Answer (score 7):

You have to include the file that has the Wordpress functions located on the main directory of the Wordpress Installation:

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);  
require_once('../../../wp-load.php');
```

../../../ = path to the main directory on your installation

I found a nice tutorial about this [here](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-loopy-ajax-powered-loops-with-jquery-and-wordpress/).

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, maybe it will help someone else.

My situation is I have a js file that uses getScript. In that script i have a bunch of .load() calls to a php file. At the top I place this.

```
if (file_exists("../../../wp-load.php"))
    {
    require_once("../../../wp-load.php");
    }
```

Change the `../` to how ever many directories your wp-load file is up.

Edit - Using WP 3.4.1