# Wordpress & JQuery: integrating WP function in a external php file & Redirecting urls to theme area

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have a external php file that queries the WP database for posts. I use the WP_Query class to customize my queries. It runs fine if I'm within the template files, but it won't when I add a new php file.

I would like to include the functions that WP uses to my file.

Ajax-nao.php

```
$categoryid = $_GET['cat'];
 $postnum = $_GET['ponum'];
 $pagenum = $_GET['panum'];

$args = array (
        'cat' => $categoryid,
        'posts_per_page' => $postnum,
        'paged' => $pagenum
);
$q = new WP_Query($args);
while( $q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();
    $post_excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
    $wrapper = '<h2 class="column-titles">' . get_the_title() . '</h2>' . '<p>' . $post_excerpt . '</p>';
    echo $wrapper;
exit();
endwhile;
echo "No results found!";
```

When I run it I get this error

> Fatal error: Class 'WP_Query' not found in I:\xampp\htdocs\dmp\wp-content\themes\dmp-v3\Ajax-nao.php on line 11

Also, is there a way to for $.get() to load the my php in my theme folder and not in the root directory?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From some research, try adding this to the top of your PHP file and change `PATHHERE` to the actual path:

```
// Include WordPress
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require_once('PATHHERE/wp-blog-header.php');
```

For reference:

[I want to run wp_query on a separate php file for an ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641545/i-want-to-run-wp-query-on-a-separate-php-file-for-an-ajax-call)

[wordpress loop with jquery .load()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130364/wordpress-loop-with-jquery-load)

Comment: If I use this, I have to place  my external php file in my root directory. Is there a way to let it stay in the theme directory?

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of ways to do this. One is to simply create a template file without any header or footer:

```
<?php
    /**
    * Template Name: AJAX NAO
    */

    $categoryid = $_GET['cat'];
    $postnum = $_GET['ponum'];
    $pagenum = $_GET['panum'];

    $args = array (
            'cat' => $categoryid,
            'posts_per_page' => $postnum,
            'paged' => $pagenum
    );
    $q = new WP_Query($args);
    while( $q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();
        $post_excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
        $wrapper = '<h2 class="column-titles">' . get_the_title() . '</h2>' . '<p>' . $post_excerpt . '</p>';
        echo $wrapper;
    exit();
    endwhile;
    echo "No results found!";
```

Then you can use that template for a new page in your WP admin. In your jQuery, call the full URL of that page.

The harder but preferred way is to create a plugin. You'd need something like:

```
<?php
/*
    Plugin Name: My AJAX NAO
    Description: Returns NAO
    Version: 1.0
    Author: You
    Author URI: http://yoursite.com
*/

// 
function nao_callback() {
    $categoryid = $_POST['cat'];
    $postnum = $_POST['ponum'];
    $pagenum = $_POST['panum'];

    $args = array (
            'cat' => $categoryid,
            'posts_per_page' => $postnum,
            'paged' => $pagenum
    );
    $q = new WP_Query($args);
    while( $q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();
        $post_excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
        $wrapper = '<h2 class="column-titles">' . get_the_title() . '</h2>' . '<p>' . $post_excerpt . '</p>';
        echo $wrapper;
    exit();
    endwhile;
    echo "No results found!";
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nao', 'nao_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_nao', 'nao_callback');
```

And then in your jquery:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {
        action: 'nao',
        cat: '1',
        ponum: '2',
        panum: '3'
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $('.js-element').html(data);
    }
});
```

Assuming `js-element` is the class name of the container you want to add the result to.